# Minoration of $\sqrt{a} -\sqrt{b} $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How can we minorate $\sqrt{a} -\sqrt{b} $ using $a$ and $b$?

Comment: What do you mean by minorate?

Comment: The word "minorate" is not a commonly used English word, even in the context of mathematics. Please explain what you mean

Comment: I think that "Minorate = find a lower bound" (at least this is the case in Portuguese).

Comment: @MatheusManzatto I agree but without more context, by far the best lower bound for $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$ is $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$ :)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I see the problem now. I completely agree with you.

Comment: Minorate = find a lower bound